# Equally spaced x-value for values that are not equally spaced

Tags: matlab, plot, axis

I'm trying to display a discrete plot with values on the x-axis that are not equally space but I want them to appear equally spaced. I would like a stem plot with the first stick not on the y-axis, and I'd also like to have an horizontal dashed line at y=1.

So far here is what I tried.

```
x = [10 50 150 3000];
y = [.6 .754 .853 .954]; 
xv = [1 2 3 4];
stem(xv,y);
set(gca,'XTickLabel',x);
```

Unfortunately, this is not what I expected. The value on the x-axis are not right and the sticks start on the y-axis and end on the figure edge.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** I initially forgot the horizontal dashed line. Added this.

---

You just need two tiny additions:

```matlab
x = [10 50 150 3000];
y = [.6 .754 .853 .954]; 
xv = [1 2 3 4];
stem(xv, y);
xlim([min(xv)-1 max(xv)+1]);   % <--
set(gca, 'xtick', xv);         % <--
set(gca, 'xticklabel', x);
```

You (also) need to explicitly set the `xtick` option, so that only these ticks are drawn, and no other.

With [`xlim`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlim.html), you can manipulate the x-axis limits. (Left and right limit might be modified to your needs.)

To add the horizontal dashed line, just add the following at the end:

```matlab
hold on;
plot([min(xv)-1 max(xv)+1], [1 1], 'k--');
hold off;
```

(Start and end points of the line might be modified to your needs.)

From Matlab R2018b on, you could also use [`yline`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/yline.html).

The output then looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When you have a sequence of values that you want to plot equally spaced without any special treatment to what each value actually is, you're essentially defining a set of **categories**.

MATLAB is good at handling these nicely without any extra trickery to lay them out uniformly on your axes if you declare the values explicitly as `categorical`.

All you need, therefore, is:

```
x = [10 50 150 3000];
y = [.6 .754 .853 .954]; 
stem(categorical(x),y);
yline(1,'--');
ylim([0 1.5]) % Make some space on the y-axis so the horizontal line doesn't sit on the top edge
```

[image: Result]